# When should I write a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel

Some people want to move code from user space to kernel space in Linux for some reason. A lot of times the reason seems to be that the code should have particularly high priority or simply "kernel space is faster".

This seems strange to me. When should I consider writing a kernel module? Are there a set of criterias?

How can I motivate keeping code in user space that (I believe) belong there?

Answer (score 25):

Rule of thumb: try your absolute **best** to keep your code in user-space. If you don't think you can, spend as much time researching alternatives to kernel code as you would writing the code (ie: a long time), and then *try again* to implement it in user-space. If you *still* can't, research more to ensure you're making the right choice, then *very cautiously* move into the kernel. As others have said, there are *very few* circumstances that dictate writing kernel modules and debugging kernel code can be quite hellish, so steer clear at all costs.

As far as concrete conditions you should check for when considering writing kernel-mode code, here are a few: Does it need access to extremely low-level resources, such as interrupts? Is your code defining a new interface/driver for hardware that *cannot* be built on top of currently exported functionality? Does your code **require** access to data structures or primitives that are not exported out of kernel space? Are you writing something that will be primarily used by *other* kernel subsystems, such as a scheduler or VM system (even here it isn't entirely necessary that the subsystem be kernel-mode: Mach has strong support for *user-mode* virtual memory pagers, so it can definitely be done)?

Answer (score 22):

There are very limited reasons to put stuff into the kernel. If you're writing device drivers it's ok. Any standard application: never.

The drawbacks are huge. Debugging gets harder, errors become more frequent and hard to find. You might compromise security and stability. You might have to adapt to kernel changes more frequently. It becomes impossible to port to other UNIX OSs.

The closest I've ever come to the kernel was a custom filesystem (with mysql in the background) and even for that we used FUSE (where the U stands for userspace).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure the question is the right way around. There should be a good reason to move things to kernel space. If there aren't any reasons, don't do it.

For one thing, debugging is made harder, and the effect of bugs is far worse (crash/panic instead of simple coredump).

Comment: Not to mention security issues (is your code 100% hacking proof? The slightest bug could become an enormous back-door!), collateral damage issues (a subtle bug can affect much more than your app), etc.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, I agree with rpj. Code has to be in user-space, unless it's REALLY necessary.

But, to emphasize your question, which condition?

Some people claims that driver has to be in the kernel, which is not true. Some drivers are not timing sensitive, in fact lots of drivers are like that.

For example, the framer, RTC timer, i2c devices, etc. Those drivers can be easily moved to user space. There are even some file-systems that are written in user-space.

You should move to kernel space where the overhead, eg. user-kernel swap, becomes unacceptable for your code to work properly.

But there are lots of way to deal with this. For example, the /dev/mem provides a good way to access your physical memory, just like you do it from the kernel space.

When people talk about going to RTOS, I'm usually skeptical.
These days, the processor is so powerful, that most of the time, the real-time aspect becomes negligible.

But even, let's say, you're dealing with SONET, and you need to do a protection switching within 50ms (actually even less, since the 50ms constrains applies to the whole ring), you still can do the switching very fast, IF your hardware supports it.

Lots of framer these days can give you a hardware support that reduces the amount of writes that you need to do. Your job is basically responds to the interrupt as quickly as possible. And Linux is not bad at all. The interrupt latency I got was less 1ms, even if I have tons of other interrupts running (eg. IDE, ethernet, etc.).

And if that's still not enough, then maybe your hardware design is wrong. Some things are better left on the hardware. And when I said hardware, I mean ASIC, FPGA, Network Processor, or other advanced logic.

Answer (score 3):

Code running in the kernel accesses memory, peripherals, system functions in ways that are different from userspace code and thus has the ability to be more efficient. Not to mention the reduced security restrictions for kernel code. However, all this usually comes  at a cost, such as increasing the possibility of opening the kernel up to security threats, locking up the OS, complicating the debugging, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If your people want really high priority, determinism, low latency etc, the right way to go is to use some real-time version of Linux (or other OS).

Also look at the preemptible kernel options etc. Exactly what you should do depends on the requirements, but to put the code in kernel modules is not likely the right solution, unless you are interfacing some hardware directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason to not move code into kernel space is that when you use it in production or commercial situations, you will have to publish that code due to the GPL agreement. A situation that many software companies don't want to come into. :)

Answer (score 0):

As general rule. Think on what you want to know and if that is something you would see in an operating system development book or class then it has a good chance to belong into the kernel. If not, keep it out of the kernel. If you  have a very good reason to break that rule, be sure, you will have enough knowledge to know it by yourself or you will be working with someone that has that knowledge.

Yes, might sound harsh, but this exactly what I meant, if you don't know, then be almost sure the answer is no, don't do it in the kernel. Moving your development to kernel space opens a giant can of worms that you must be sure to be able to handle.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need lower latency, higher throughput, etc., it is probably **cheaper** to buy a faster computer than to develop kernel code.

Kernel modules *may* be faster (due to less context switches, less system call overhead, and less interruptions), and certainly *do* run at very high priority. If you want to export a small amount of fairly simple code into kernel space, this might be OK. That is, if a small piece of code is found to be crucial to performance, *and* is the sort of code that would benefit from being placed in kernel mode, then it may be justified to place it there.

But moving large parts of your program into kernel space should be avoided unless all other options are completely exhausted. Aside from the difficulty of doing so, the performance benefit is not likely to be very large.

Comment: Cost doesn't matter if faster computers don't exist.  But for those cases, moving to a realtime OS is probably better than subverting the kernel.

Answer (score -5):

If you're asking such a question, then you shouldn't go to the kernel layer. Basically just wondering means you don't need to. The time of the context switch is so negligible that it doesn't matter anyway these days.